# libi2c linking cmake

Tags: cmake

Tengo este CMakeLists.txt y necesito relacionar la librería libi2c-dev con el ejecutable. Soy nuevo usando CMake y estoy teniendo problemas.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(IMU VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(EXEC IMU)
find_package(libi2c-dev QUIET)
include_directories(AFTER ${I2CDEV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${EXEC} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC} ${I2CDEV_LIBS})
```

Si empleo la consola puedo compilar el programa con

```
gcc IMU.cpp -o IMU -Wall -li2c
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente te falta en el proyecto el módulo "Findlibi2c-dev.cmake" que es necesario para que funcione `find_package()`. No es un módulo estándar de CMake, así que has de conseguirlo por ahí. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crea un subdirectorio "cmake" en tu proyecto.
2. Descarga en dicho subdirectorio el módulo "Findlibi2c-dev.cmake" de alguna parte, por ejemplo:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrpn/vrpn/master/cmake/Findlibi2c-dev.cmake`

3. Modifica tu "CMakeLists.txt" para incluir la línea siguiente, antes de `find_package()`:

`list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")`

Con eso sería suficiente, pero te aconsejo también que evites esto:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)
```

Es preferible especificar manualmente cada uno de los fuentes:

```
set(SOURCES uno.cpp dos.cpp etc.cpp)
```